# Need to remove duplicate entries in table - two field combinations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where a parent can have several children... set up like the following:

```
id, parent, child
```

Some sample data would look like this:

```
id  parent_id  child_id
1   2          1
2   2          3
3   2          3
```

So for this example, I would want to remove the duplicate entry where `parent_id=2` and `child_id=3`

I do not have access to add keys or indexes to this table, so I need to manually remove all entries where a parent has multiple instances of the same child.

For example, I can't have `Parent=2`, `Child=3` more than once in the table.

I need to go through and delete ALL BUT ONE instance of where `Parent=2` and `Child=3`

Suggestions?

I'd like to use one statement if possible.

Comment: Yes but provide some sample data and expected output. More importantly do you have a primary key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysql's multi-table delete syntax to delete from the table when joined appropriately to itself:

```
delete b
from mytable a
join mytable b on a.id < b.id
  and a.parent_id = b.parent_id
  and a.child_id = b.child_id
```

The join condition `a.id < b.id` is necessary to prevent rows from joining to themselves and identifies the duplicate as the row with the highest id of the duplicate pair.

Answer (score 0):

This will drop all the duplicate rows.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE TblName ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (parent, child);
```

Or

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpTable (id INT);

INSERT  tmpTable
        (id)
SELECT  id
FROM    YourTable yt
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    YourTabe yt2
        WHERE   yt2.parent = yt.parent 
                AND yt2.child = yt.child 
                AND yt2.id > yt.id
        );

DELETE  
FROM    YourTable
WHERE   ID IN (SELECT id FROM tmpTable);
```

Comment: I can't add indexes to the table or run alter statements... I can only delete from existing table.

Comment: @user3299633 Try It now, added 1 more solution. Hope It helps.